# How to control when a SQL Server temp table is disconnected?

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, ms-access, pass-through

I'd like to control when a (global) temporary table in SQL Server is removed (session disconnected). The global temp table is created using MS Access pass through query. It seems to disconnect based on a timer and I'd like to have more control over when Access disconnects from the temp table.

> 1. Pass through query ran in MS Access.
> 2. Temp table now available in SQL Server. (I.e., ##TempTable1)
> 3. 30 minutes later, SQL Server temp table (##TempTable1) is no longer available.

Temp tables with other software, such as SSMS and Toad keep temp tables open until the session is completely closed. Access seems to remove temp table connection based on how long they've been created.

I've tried keeping the pass through query results (the actual query results) open in `MS Access` to see if the temp table will continue to exist, without luck.

I'm hoping for a setting/property where the pass through query keeps it's connection with SQL Server in order to persist the temp table on SQL Server.

**[UPDATE]:**
After timing the exact persistence period, the temp table seems to still exist:

1. Query the temp table (##TempTable1) in MS Access every 5 minutes
2. Results present = temp table still exists
3. TempTable1 has now persisted for 1h 20m

Re-querying the temp table must be resetting some connection timer.

Comment: Does the PassThru query run in a module that is then exited? thus dropping the connection?  Is there some other way that another module could drop the connection for this app?

Comment: Perhaps. More specifically, the pass-through query definition is dynamically populated with a SQL string and then executed using DoCmd.RunSql(sql).

Comment: SQL Server drops global temporary tables when all sessions that use the table end. That's the way it works. You have to monitor your sessions and find out when do they get dropped. It's completely logical that re-querying the temp table resets the MS Access session timer.

Comment: Oh. A persistent temporary table?

Comment: Jordan, a temp table is a *temporary thing*... that is what it's meant to be... I would not hack around tricking out the wanted behaviour, just to simulate a persistant table. Why don't you create a normal table for this? You can 1) name it *tmpSomeSame*, 2) you might create a schema *tmp* and call your table *tmp.SomeName* and 3) (if this is a matter of rights) you can create a complete side-database on the same server and use *sideDb.dbo.SomeTable*.

Comment: +1 for Shnugo above.    If the  example was using a #temp table, then we have maybe some issues here. However, a ##temp table is global to all users - not just the current user connection. give that global ##temp tables vs that of  #temp is being used here, then I would create a permanent table - even if I had to drop it after its been used.

Comment: OzrenTkalcecKrznaric - Appreciate the help. That's the way I understand it as well. I'll see if I can more closely monitor the temp table existence. Shnugo - The goal is to have a temporary (##global) table, yes. There is no "hacking around" to reference your assumed response. Ultimately, the question is to understand the mechanics how how to persist a temporary table as seen fit.

Comment: Not to be rude. But if multiple experienced users tell you "this is not the correct usage for a ##temp table", it is worth listening to them. And what else than "hacking around the normal behavior" could requerying a temp table every 5 minutes, just to make it persist, be?